# Concurrent operations in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I wanted to understand something about the internals of spark streaming executions.

If I have a stream X, and in my program I send stream X to function A and function B:

1. In function A, I do a few transform/filter operations etc. on X->Y->Z to create stream Z. Now I do a forEach Operation on Z and print the output to a file.
2. Then in function B, I reduce stream X -> X2 (say min value of each RDD), and print the output to file

Are both functions being executed for each RDD in parallel? How does it work?

Thanks

--- Comments from Spark Community ----

I am adding comments from the spark community -

If you execute the collect step (foreach in 1, possibly reduce in 2) in two threads in the driver then both of them will be executed in parallel. Whichever gets submitted to Spark first gets executed first - you can use a semaphore if you need to ensure the ordering of execution, though I would assume that the ordering wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eswara's answer is seems right but it does not apply to your use case as your separate transformation DAG's (`X->Y->Z` and `X->X2`) have a common DStream ancestor in `X`. This means that when the actions are run to trigger each of these flows, the transformation `X->Y` and the transformation `X->X2` **cannot** happen at the same time. What will happen is the partitions for RDD `X` will be either computed or loaded from memory (if cached) for each of these transformations separately in a non-parallel manner.

Ideally what would happen is that the transformation `X->Y` would resolve and then the transformations `Y->Z` and `X->X2` would finish in parallel as there is no shared state between them. I believe Spark's pipelining architecture would optimize for this. You can ensure faster computation on `X->X2` by persisting DStream `X` so that it can be loaded from memory rather than being recomputed or being loaded from disk. See [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) for more information on persistence.

What would be interesting is if you could provide the replication storage levels `*_2` (e.g. `MEMORY_ONLY_2` or `MEMORY_AND_DISK_2`) to be able to run transformations concurrently on the same source. I think those storage levels are currently only [useful against lost partitions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#which-storage-level-to-choose) right now, as the duplicate partition will be processed in place of the lost one.

Comment: -Thanks for the explanation. This is in essence what I thought. I will try to execute the application and see the behavior.. I am not running it on a cluster, but in local mode right now.. I will get back to you with the results, and accept your answer if that is indeed the behavior :)

Comment: One more follow up. I do a rdd.collect() call at the end of each forEach Operation, and the traverse through the returned list. I understand that the collect function sends this information to the driver. Will the traversal of the list be sequential, or parallel (I am assuming that it's inside the driver). The traversal of the list is also within the callback function of forEach()

Comment: You are correct in that the data transmitted through `collect()` is sent back to the driver. Any traversal you subsequently make on this data will be executed solely on the driver, so be careful of what data you send back. And while [there are ways](http://www.scalaformachinelearning.com/2014/01/performance-scala-parallel-collections.html) to process this data in parallel on a single machine (depending on your driver architecture), typically this does mean that you will process the driver data sequentially.

Comment: Hey @tsar2512, did that help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
It's similar to spark's execution model which uses DAGs and lazy evaluation except that streaming runs the DAG repeatedly on each fresh batch of data.
In your case, since the DAGs(or sub-DAGs of larger DAG if one prefers to call that way) required to finish each action(each of the 2 **foreach**s you have) do not have common links all the way back till source, they run completely in parallel.The streaming application as a whole gets X  executors(JVMs) and Y cores(threads) per executor allotted at the time of application submission to resource manager.At any time, a given task(i.e., thread) in X*Y tasks will be executing a part or whole of **one** of these DAGs.Note that any 2 given threads of an application, whether in same executor or otherwise, can execute different actions of the same application at the same time.